# How are private objects passed in java?

Tags: java, object, reference, parameter-passing

Quick question i imagine, but i'm having trouble getting a clear answer from googling.

So i have 3 objects. Card, Deck, Player.
Both Deck and Player have an array of cards and both are declared in main.

Can i do the following in main() to get a reference to a card from deck into player?

```
player.getcard(deck.draw())
```

deck.draw() returns a Card and getcard is: `player.getcard(Card card)`

And yes, I'm coming from c++.

Comment: yes, you can do that. Have you tried it? If you can't it would help to see the definitions of those methods.

Comment: yes, certainly you can do this.

Comment: "In short: Java has pointers and is strictly pass-by-value. There's no funky rules. It's simple, clean, and clear". Read the great explanation from Scott at http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: couldn't test. I don't have access to my computer for a week or so and am stuck using school computers without compilers. I decided to define some of my classes on paper. After doing quite a bit, i realized i wasn't sure if i could pass objects like this. thanks.

Comment: Java passing is always `copy of reference`.

Comment: @Jasonw Java doesn't have pointers.  Java has references instead of pointers, much like the safe subset of C# does: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx

Comment: @AdamMihalcin I am just quote from Scott. But he has many explanation in details with example too.

Comment: my thoughts were: "wait, maybe setting the objects to private means they can only be used by that instance of the class." I guess private just means nothing can access it without a public method returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, assuming that `getcard` actually puts its parameter into some private field in the `Player` class.

Long(er) answer: In Java, there are only two things available to you - primitives and references.  The primitives are the numeric types, characters, and booleans.  Everything else is an object, and all objects are references.  So, when you write

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

a new object of type `Foo` is created and on the (garbage-collected) heap, and a reference, which you can also think of as a "pointer," is placed on the stack.  The Java language gives you few real ways to examine that reference, though (you can't cast it to a pointer or a `long`, for example) so you can just think of it as an opaque handle.

So, when you write

```
player.getcard(deck.draw())
```

the call

```
deck.draw()
```

returns a reference to an object of type `Card`, and that object is passed to the `player.getcard` method.  Then, if the `Player` class looks something like

```
public class Player {
    private List<Card> cards;
    // ...
    public void getcard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }
}
```

then later calls to methods in `Player` that access the `cards` private field will see that the return value of `deck.draw()` has been added to `cards`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that the "draw" method in the Deck class is visible (package private and in the same package as the class with the main method, OR a public method). Having said that, your methods could have better names:

```
player.drawCard(Card aCard)
```

would be nicer than "getcard" which makes it seem like you're getting a card FROM the player.

Comment: i made up the example, but yeah, i guess "get" should be reserved for getters.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, so long as `getcard()`'s return type is `Card`, then yes, you can do it.  It would have to look like something below for it to be properly contained in the `Player` object.  Note that this assumes that the `getCard()` method from the Deck class is declared as `static`, meaning that you don't have to create an instance of it to get the cards from it.

```
public class Player {

    private Card[] hand;

    public Player(int handSize) {
        hand = new Card[handSize];
    }


    ...

    public void getCard(int pos) {
        // Some logic to handle behavior with 0 cards, handSize cards, etc...
        hand[pos] = Deck.getCard();
    }
}
```